# Matching lists when elements are not ordered

Tags: python, list, dictionary

let's say I have a list `b=['m','NN']` and a dictionary `dict={'b':['NN','m','big']}` and I want to use the function to retrieve the key 'b' if the elements of the list `b` are in `dict[b]`
(so let's say using `[k for k,v in dict.items()]`.
Now how do I do that if the elements in `b` are not ordered as the elements in `dict[b]` and supposing I cannot change the order in the b list?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
 [k for k, v in dict.items() if all((x in v) for x in b)]
```

For example:

```
>>> b=['m','NN']
>>> dict={'b':['NN','m','big'], 'a':['NN', 'q']}
>>> [k for k, v in dict.items() if all((x in v) for x in b)]
['b']
```

(Note that it is a bad idea to name your dictionary `dict`, since `dict` is the name of the data type).

Answer (score 4):

Not certain I understand what you're asking, but if what you're after is the list of keys in dictionary `d` with values which are super-sets of the list `b`, you could use something like:

```
b=['m','NN']
d={'b':['NN','m','big'], 'a':['jj','r']}
[k for k,v in d.items() if set(b) <= set(v)]
```

(I changed the name of your example dictionary as `dict` is a built-in class.)

Comment: I would also move it out of the comprehension ... and use `set_b.issubset(v)` since you wouldt have to convert v to set for that